# webdriver failing to update web address

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to collect addresses of several links shown on a website with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/seongwoo/Desktop/USHL data scraping/chromedriver.exe')

url = ("https://www.ushl.com/view#/schedule")
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@ng-model ='selectedSeason']/option[@label='2018-19']").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@ng-model ='selectedTeam']/option[@label='Youngstown Phantoms']").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@ng-model ='selectedMonth']/option[@Value='12']").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@ng-click=\"location='home';\"]").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="ht-btn-submit ng-binding"]').click()
time.sleep(10)

window_before = driver.window_handles[0]    #store the monther window's handle 

buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ht-table-game-report')   #use this instead of 'by_xpath'

for button_index in range(len(buttons)):
    time.sleep(3)
    
    buttons[button_index].click()    ##this is where you decide which of the reports to click on 

    #after clicking the link store the window handle of newly opened window as
    window_after = driver.window_handles[1] 

    #then execute the switch to window method to move to newly opened window

    driver.switch_to.window(window_after)     
    current_URL = driver.current_url            #Hthis does not seem to update the address

    print(current_URL)

    webUrl  = urllib.request.urlopen(current_URL)

    driver.switch_to.window(window_before)
```

I would have thought

```
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)     
current_URL = driver.current_url
```

would take care of updating the address after clicking on the link.

I would appreciate it if someone could point out why `current_URL` is forever stuck on the first updated address and fails to get updated afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Because `window_after = driver.window_handles[1]` refers always to the first page you opened. To update your window and move to the most recent page you opened you should use the `button_index` to define `window_after` as `window_after = driver.window_handles[button_index+1]`

Comment: Not true, if you have one window open ```driver.window_handles[0]``` will be the first page not ```[1]```. Also the ```button_index``` does not represent the window index in no means

Comment: if you want to get the url of the page opened after clicking a button you can use the index of the button lists to move to the page you opened by clicking that button. The output using `window_after = driver.window_handles[button_index+1]` will be the list of the urls of the pages that the driver opened

Comment: You are supposing that the OP does not close the previous one, that each link are clicked. If the window index increases you better use ```[-1]```

Comment: I'll remove the downvote, but the statement that the first page opened is index=1 is incorrect. The first page opened with the driver.get() is always index=0. Thanks for fixing the index in your provided answer

Comment: Window handle order isn't guarenteed though, right? https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/386

Answer (score 0):

Each time you iterate a new window will be opened, this increase the number of opened windows and `driver.window_handles[1]`  will always be the second window opened.

A quick solution is to always use the last opened window using `[-1]`:

```
driver.window_handles[-1]
```

To return to the main window:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

You could also close the last opened window prior to switch back to the original window

```
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Comment: I don't think window order is guarenteed: https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/386

Comment: Wow very interesting.. that also means that ```[0]``` could not be the default one either. Thread is old, but we should assume it is still the case.

Comment: Right. Not sure if that applies to just java, or python too. But order shouldn't be assumed, so you need to compare the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Order of windows handles can not be assumed. There is a good code snippet provided here:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/

```
# Open URL
driver.get("https://seleniumhq.github.io")

# Setup wait for later
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Store the ID of the original window
original_window = driver.current_window_handle

# Check we don't have other windows open already
assert len(driver.window_handles) == 1

# Click the link which opens in a new window
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "new window").click()

# Wait for the new window or tab
wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))

# Loop through until we find a new window handle
for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
    if window_handle != original_window:
        driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
        break

# Wait for the new tab to finish loading content
wait.until(EC.title_is("SeleniumHQ Browser Automation"))
```

Basically you need to ensure you've selected the right window, not just assume.